# React-Native webview component not persisting cookies in Auth0 hosted page

Tags: react-native, cookies, webview, google-tag-manager, auth0

### Background:

I have a GTM (with Tealium) script [placed in the head](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web#custom_web_installations) of an [auth0 hosted page](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/auth0-universal-login).

This auth0 hosted page is called from a *Web* client, and a *React Native* client - both using [auth0's sdk method](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js#initialization) `webAuth.authorize()`.

### Call from *Web* client (expected behaviour):

- User auths from client
- redirect to hosted auth0 page
- GTM inited and fires some events

The cookies look good and are persisting here.

### Call from *React Native* client (no cookies present in [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) redirect):

- User auths from client
- Webview component pops in-built browser to sign in, navigating to the same auth0 page
- no cookies are present (none at all)
- GTM does not fire

### Versions of deps:

- ios version: "12.1"
- react-native-webview: "^8.0.4"
- react-native: "0.63.3"
- react-native-auth0: "^2.6.0"

### What the React-Native WebView component looks like:

```
<WebView
    ref={webViewRef}
    source={{ uri: source }}
    sharedCookiesEnabled
    thirdPartyCookiesEnabled
    domStorageEnabled
  />
```

### Checks:

- Standard Safari settings to enable third-party cookies

### Thoughts:

There must be something wrong with the WebView?